# Color Panel for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am developing an iPhone application in which I want to allow the user to select a color from a panel that is displayed. For Desktop application, the framework provides NSColorPanel. But, iPhone SDK does not provide this option. Is there any sample or alternate method to display such color panel?

Thanks and Regards
Deepa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [blog](http://www.fabiancanas.com/entry/iphone-color-picker) post to start with.  My guess is you're after a modal view that'll popup so you can select a color, then dismiss it to continue.

Comment: Thank you petert. This is what I expected.